# DAX query to select values between two given date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new in DAX query and trying to to get the distinct list of `promotion_name` from the `promotion` table between two dates which are from other two columns of that table. I have written the below DAX query for a measure. However, I am getting an error. I am sure the query is not correct. Can I get some help?

```
Measure = 
CALCULATE(VALUES(promotion[promotion_name]),
FILTER (ALL(promotion),
    promotion[start_date] >= DATE(1997,1,1) &&
    promotion[end_date] <= DATE(1997,12,31)))
```

Basically I want to implement the this SQL query in DAX:

```
select promotion_name
from promotion
where start_date >= '1998-01-01 00:00:00' AND
        end_date <= '1998-12-31 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Basically I want to implement the this SQL query in DAX: " Select promotion_name from promotion
where start_date >= '1998-01-01 00:00:00' AND end_date <= '1998-12-31 00:00:00' "

Comment: A measure only returns a single value, not a list or table. What are you trying to do with the distinct list?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how can I produce it in DAX, if it is possible in DAX as like we can do it in SQL.

Answer (score 5):

You are nearly there. As stated by Alexis, this DAX expression returns a table and not a single value like a measure. So use CALCULATETABLE in stead of CALCULATE. The ALL function in the FILTER expression is not necessary here. So try this in `New Table` on the Modeling-tab:

```
Table =
CALCULATETABLE (
    VALUES ( promotion[promotion_name] ),
    FILTER (
        promotion,
        promotion[start_date] >= DATE ( 1997, 1, 1 )
            && promotion[end_date] <= DATE ( 1997, 12, 31 )
    )
)
```

Note that `VALUES ( promotion[promotion_name] )` will return the distinct values. If you need all values with duplicates, you need to replace `VALUES ( promotion[promotion_name] )` with `SELECTCOLUMNS('promotion',"promotion_name",'promotion'[promotion_name])`.